# juju bootstrap node roles and responsibilities

Tags: juju

1. What is the role of the juju bootstrap node beside connecting to the deployment cloud? (the one we call juju bootstrap on)
2. Is this the node with the zookeeper?
3. Is zookeeper running as daemon or just runs with juju call?
4. What happens if I lose my bootstrap node?
5. Can I have multiple bootstrap nodes for one environment in the cloud?

Answer (score 3):

1. This is the node where juju is running on. It is the basic node in your environment and it will control all the other nodes.
2. Yes, Zookeeper is on this node.
3. Zookeeper is a java-application which is running as a deamon on the first node - the bootstrap node. It is runnig with the user zookeeper.
4. If this node is destroyed, your whole environment is destroyed. You can try this by type `juju terminate-machine 0`. Juju won't do it and give you an error.
5. No, one environment can have only one bootstrap node. With this node is the whole environment build and administrated, so it can't exist more then one bootrap node in this organization.